# Rotate varnish log with rsyslog in magento bitnami stack

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, magento, varnish, rsyslog

I created an ec2 instance with Magento Bitnami stack on it (ami-04a541d64dbfb377e). I used the command

```sh
varnishncsa -a -w /path/to/varnish/logs/mylog.log -D
```

to save the log into a file and monitoring it with a cloudwatch agent to push the log to cloudwatch and it works fine (actually varnish is spin up by bitnami script as a subunit of the service bitnami).

Now, I need to rotate the log when the file */path/to/varnish/logs/mylog.log* gets to a certain file size for example 10MB.

On the system is used rsyslog.

I tried to use this guide from rsyslog doc to achieve that [link](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/master/tutorials/log_rotation_fix_size.html), literally copying it and changing the path of the files.

The result is that I end up having 2 files(*/path/to/varnish/logs/mylog.log* and */path/to/varnish/logs/mylog.log.1*) where all the logs go into the second one (also exceeding the specified file size).

where I am wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are having occurs because Varnish still has the file descriptor open after you moved it on the filesystem.

Unless you can tell the program to restart logging directly after moving (with something like SIGHUP or systemctl restart varnish), you will have to use another method for rotation than moving files around to which are written into at that time.